# Run command after login from specific tty

Tags: command-line, login, tty

I'd like to achieve this: 1) When user (anybody) logs in to tty1, then some specific command(s) will run automatically. 2) When user (anybody) logs in to other tty, then no command(s) will run automatically.

For example: When I log in to tty1, `free` command will run.
I put the commands into `.profile` file, but it applies to all tty.
Is there any solution how to make this possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple condition to determine which tty you are logging into:

```
if [[ "$(tty)" == "/dev/tty1" ]]
 then
  # do whatever you want here
fi
```

also if you want to your command get run for all users, instead of `.profile` put it into  `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Yup, I use exactly the same structure to run a report on `df` and couple other commands myself. Good way to go, although note that `[[` is specific to bash

Comment: Sir, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: @WantToLearn You're welcome :)